# HDD extremely slow although SMART seems to be healthy

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I've had this hard drive for over two years now. A week ago, it decides to slow down to a crawl in Windows - even after doing the usual things to fix it (disabling Superfetch, closing programs, etc.) and it still was extremely slow. I decided to wipe the hard drive clean in a linux live cd (dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M) and install that distro of linux (Ubuntu). It fails to partition the ext4 system. I tried wiping the drive and installing Windows again, but it won't let me (either in UEFI or BIOS). I had checked my smart data and while the SMART health passedthe raw value of the command timeout is suspiciously high - 5,227,170,103,295 to be exact. Is this bad for my 1 TB hard drive?

Comment: What errors are you getting when you try to partition it?

Comment: what DMA mode is is currently using?

Comment: If you keep wiping the software and the problem remains then it's the hardware not the software

Comment: @oldmud0 When installing Windows, in BIOS mode it gives me the "Failed to prepare to reboot for the next phase" and in UEFI it hangs on copying files.

Comment: @RichieFrame I have no clue.

Comment: @Anonymous Check your UEFI/BIOS settings for Direct Memory Access mode or DMA mode or something like that. If it's off, turn it on, or vice versa.

Comment: @RichieFrame, "dma mode" is bush league unless you are using a 15 year old IDE hard drive.  That is to say, there is no such thing with SATA hard drives, which is pretty much anything less than 10 years old.

Comment: @psusi actually it does matter, SATA uses DMA only, and it can be forced into the slowest DMA mode through a registry modification, making things hilariously slow. I have seen many computers over the years with a sudden slowness traced to that reg key

Comment: @RichieFrame, SATA always uses dma, and so there are no "dma modes".  SATA simply operates at 1.5/3/6 Gbps all the time.  "dma mode" refers to how fast the IDE bus clocked dma ( data ) transfers, which were handled differently than the regular PIO command transfers.  Even if a driver tried to foolishly map the sata signaling speed to a "dma mode" ( 66/100/133 MB/s ) and used that as a signal to fall back from 3 Gbps to 1.5 Gbps, that is still faster than most hard disks ( as opposed to SSDs ) can go anyhow, and so wouldn't account for horrible slowness, let alone total inability to format.

Comment: @psusi not true, SATA devices can support UDMA, multi word DMA, and even PIO modes. The SATA, AHCI, and ATA specifications require it

Comment: @RichieFrame, no, they don't because UDMA and multi word DMA ( 32 bits instead of 16 at a time ) deal with what pins, and at what frequencies they use in the IDE ribbon.  With SATA, everything goes across the serial bus ( one bit at a time ) operating at 1.5/3/6 Gbps and is encoded in a FIS ( packet ).  The only difference between PIO and DMA in SATA is whether the data is going to/from the taskfile shadow registers in the AHCI controller ( PIO ) or main system ram ( DMA ).  SATA does not have any transfer mode that operates at 66/100/133 MB/s.

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection between your hard drive and your motherboard. It's possible that the SATA cable is loose.